# WIX Installer not displaying the custom image of WixUI Dialog correctly

Tags: wix, installation

In my `WIX` installer I'm using a custom `WixUIDialogBmp` image for installer's `Welcome and Completion` pages. But as shown below, the image is not displaying correctly. I'm trying to follows this [official documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) from `WIX. **Question**: What I may be missing and how can it be corrected. **Note**: The issue seems to be that the dialog is showing too much margin on the left despite the fact that the text in the image itself is aligned to the extreme left. But this is just a guess on my part.

**Installer's Welcome Dialog:**

[image]

**Installer's Completion Dialog:**

[image]

Following is the actual image that I am using for `<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="My_product_WelcomCompletion.bmp"/>`. The image `My_product_WelcomCompletion.bmp` is of size 420 x 312 and the text of the image is left aligned. **Note**: Clicking on the image below will give you a better idea of the image:

[image]

Comment: I don't have time to check and answer this right now, but maybe have a look at this project on github: https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. I don't have time to check and answer this right now, but maybe have a look at this project on github: https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme. Maybe you already have it - sort of looks like you may.

Also, you can find more advanced WiX samples and tutorials from [the IsWix project](https://github.com/iswix-llc). Essentially a GUI front end for generating WiX MSI files. [Here are the actual tutorials](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials). And the tool itself: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix. And [the blog](http://iswix.com/).